# Swift: Working with for and array

Tags: swift

I started to learn Swift but I have some problems like I want to sum two arrays and put them in a third array and I have to do it with `for` loop.

```
var ar1 = [1,3,5,7,9]
var ar2 = [2,4,6,8,10]
var ar3 : [Int] = [5]

for i in 0... ar1.count-1   {
    // for loop for index
    ar3[i] = ar1[i] + ar2[i]
}
```

But I get an out of range error. I tried a lot but I could not solve it.

Comment: One way to do it is to initialize your `var3` array with 5 zeros: `var arr3 = [Int](repeating: 0, count: 5)`

Comment: Or just the usual: `let ar3 = zip(ar1, ar2).map { $0.0 + $0.1 }`. Safe and short :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks more like C or Java than swift, but you're on the right track.  There are many other ways to do this, but this code is very similar to what you were trying to do:

```
func example() {
    let array1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

    let array2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

    var array3 = [Int]()

    for i in 0 ..< array1.count {
        array3.append(array1[i] + array2[i])
    }
    for element in array3 {
        print("\(element)")
    }
}
```

Use "let" if the variable never changes once you defined it.

I added a loop at the bottom so you can verify the results, and also so you can see that you don't need "i" in loops.

Comment: Thanks a lot but there is a question  can i use it for 2d array too?

Comment: What do you mean?  I am using 1st and 2nd arrays and putting the results in the 3rd.

Comment: Let me explain : i have two 2D array and i want to multiple them like this but they are 2D is it possible with this algorithm and add to another 2D array

Comment: OK. That's a different question.  Please accept this one (click on the checkmark) and write out what you need for your second problem after you understand this code. But you should try to solve it yourself first! Then I'll look at what you've tried and try to help out again. Good luck!